# Simple question, retrieving an updated collection of nhibernate objects from the parent

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, collections

I have a pretty easy question regarding nHibernate but I couldn't really find an answer on google.

Let's say I have a mapped `Member` object that holds a 1:n foreign key to `Mail` objects. I would like to retrieve the current collection of mail items for a user when he enters his inbox. If I call `memberInstance.Mail` (of type IList<\Mail>) it brings back the mail collection but doesn't reflect the new mail that was added since the memberInstance is saved in the cache during login and doesn't make a  round trip to the database. If I create a `RetrieveMailForUser` method, pass it a Member instance and then call code such as `Session.CreateCriteria<Mail>` I get the current mail for any given member and everything but it seems extraneous to have a Mail collection on the Member variable if I never use it as well as having a collection in the member var that isn't up to date. I could refresh the member every time the user checks his inbox and save it to the cache but this seems to have a lot of overhead. I feel like I'm missing some basic principal of nHibernate. Please help. Thanks!

Code that calls the member:

```
      public static Member GetLoggedInUser()
        {
             var member = (Member) HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_NAME];

            if(member != null && 
!NHibernateSessionManager.IsEntityAttachedToCurrentSession(member))
                NHibernateSessionManager.AttachEntityToSession(member);
            return member;


        }
```

E

Comment: you mention that changes to the collection aren't reflected in the cached item. I believe your problem lies there- the changes you make to an object SHOULD be reflected when you re-get that item from the cache. can you provide some more information regarding how you initialy retrieve the Member object and persist it?

Comment: Sorry it's saved in the ASP net session and not the cache, I edited my original question with the code that retrieves the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your post I derive two contradicting requirements:

1. You want an object (Member) in the cache, which should not be updated according to what happens in the database. It is in the very nature of a cache NOT to automatically reload anything or trying to attempt to do so.
2. You want Mails in the Mails collection of the Member object to be updated whenever accessed (and therefore disregarding what was in the cache at the moment of retrieving the Member object for the first time).

If you want to stick to the first approach, you must update the Member object in the cache directly whenever a new Mail is created for that object (calling member.AddMail(mail) or something like that). I don't know whether that is feasible, since you apparently keep Member in the session, and that would require accessing Member objects of another session.

If you also want 'up to date' list of mails, I guess there is no way around either re-loading your mail list explicitly, reloading your entire object, or just loading the mails in the way you suggested it above already (RetrieveMailForUser). In that case, you can confidently remove the Mails collection in the Member object. You don't have to map collections if you don't need them.

Comment: I marked your response as an answer but I still have a couple of questions. First I use the automapper to map the classes so I don't think I can safely take it out, what do you think? Second, how do you reload the mail list explicitly, is there an nhibernate function or do I call a 'RetrieveMailForUser' to repopulate it? Thanks for the answer btw

Comment: I'm not familiar with automapper, but have you tried just removing the Mails collection in the Member class? For reloading, in your case calling 'RetrieveMailForUser' seems just fine for me.